# Highcharts Pyramid Chart displays no data with JSON, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

When using JSON with a pyramid chart in Highcharts, I don't get any errors in the console log but no data is displayed.

I have charts.php which outcome is this:

```
{"success":1,"data":[{"name":"John Spoon","data":300}, {"name":"Dave Jones","data":200},{"name":"Other","data":500}]}
```

This is what I've tried, which returns no data.

```
<div id="chart"  style=
                        "height:600px;width:100%;"></div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#chart").html("Loading Activity Log Graph...");

    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pyramid',
            renderTo: 'chart',
            marginRight: 100
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Activity',
            x: -50
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                    softConnector: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        name: 'Activity Count',
        series: [{}]
   };

    $.ajax({
        url: "charts.php",
        type:'post',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            options.series = data.data;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);          
        }
    });

}); 
</script>
```

This is my desired outcome, showing without the use of JSON:
http://jsfiddle.net/0dyy44hz/

What do I need to change for it to show data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [pyramid example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pyramid), the data must be in the form of a single series with each data point as an array of `[name, value]`.  You have two options, change your PHP to output the correct format or modify the PHP output in javascript.  Since you didn't post your PHP code, I'll do the later:

```
var data = {"success":1,"data":[{"name":"John Spoon","data":300}, {"name":"Dave Jones","data":200},{"name":"Other","data":500}]};    

options.series = [{
    data: $.map(data.data, function(i){ // loop outputted data
        return [[i.name, i.data]]; // coerce into an array of [name,value]
    })
}];
```

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/0dyy44hz/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried changing the ajax success function from mine to `success: function(data){
  
  options.series = [{
        data: $.map(data.data, function(i){
            return [[i.name, i.data]];
        })
  }];

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  
  }` but I get a formatting error in the console log which directs me to here: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14

Comment: Ignore the above, I had changed something in the PHP which was corrupting it. This works, thanks!